# Find value at address

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying this code:

```
int main()
{
    char *ch="hello";
    printf("%u",&ch);
    return 0;
}
```

From the above `printf()` statement I have address of ch i.e `65524`
My question is Can i find value if any address is given like `*(65524)` rather than `*(&ch)`?

Comment: By the way, the above prints the address of the **pointer itself,** and not the address of the first char. And you get the format specifier wrong too. You print pointers using `%p` (and also pointers need to be cast to `void *` when printed.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes actually I tried your solution too. Firstly i used *(unsigned char*)65524 and using %p i tried like this *(unsigned char*)(oxFFF4). The output of both is same.Can You please clarify the difference b/w both??

Comment: I just did. The one is the address of the pointer holding the address of the first character. The other is the address of the first character itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
printf("%d\n", *(unsigned char *) 65524);
```

If the address does not point to a valid object, you are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Isn't `unsigned char` promoted to `unsigned int`?

Comment: No, it is promoted to `int`